# ember unit test route - this is undefined

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I try to write my first unit test for a route.

**project/files**

```
actions: {
  afterSave(savedFile){
    // ... some code
    let controller = this.controllerFor('project.files');
    // ...
  }
}
```

**the test:**

```
test('save file', function(assert) {
  let route = this.subject();
  console.log(route);
  let project;
  Ember.run(() => {
    project = route.get('store').createRecord('project', {
      id: '1',
      name: 'test'
    });

    let afterSave = route.get('actions.afterSave');
    afterSave(project);
  });  

  assert.ok(true);
})
```

The problem that I am getting *TypeError: Cannot read property 'controllerFor' of undefined*.
It looks like `this` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at [Testing Routes](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/testing-routes/) section from Ember Guides, you can see its suggestion is to separate the action and the function.
I can suggest it.
It uses `send` method of routes, such as: `route.send('afterSave');`

But if you only want to make run your code, call `afterSave` action from your test code such as: `afterSave.bind(route)(project);`. Ref: [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) (I don't suggest this. Also I don't suggest you to retrieve action such as: `route.get('actions.afterSave')`)